# CSS Font Face makes multiple requests in chrome developer tool

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools, font-face

I am using font face to download font file from the server.

The problem is, when i see the chrome network tab i see multiple request made to fetch the same font file.

The first request made has 200 status code and rest of the requests are having 304 (Not Modified)

Interestingly this happens only in chrome. i tested in safari and firefox and they are sending only one request.

below is my code snippet

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('https://example.com/font.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
$font-family: 'MyFont', sans-serif !important;
$font-weight: 400;
```

Please let me know your comments

Comment: Can you edit to provide a working example?

Comment: All the requests are to an identical url? (`https://example.com/font.ttf` for example). Maybe you included the font definition file more than one in you `scss` file.

Comment: I have found the same in chrome. I have a JS file that is shows as 304 and then not found. I rarely use chrome developer tools

Comment: I also have this problem. I'm using fonts from Google and FontAwesome. With each refresh I see between 50-1000 requests to the same file with the 304 response.